# 'Would you prefer for me to do X?' or 'Would you prefer me to do X?'—which is better in English and why?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, conditionals

For example, is it better to say

> Would you prefer for me to come in today or tomorrow?

or

> Would you prefer me to come in today or tomorrow?

What is the grammatical reason for including the 'for' after 'prefer'—or for leaving it out?

Comment: The _for_ marks the infinitive subject in the direct object complement clause _for me to come in today_, just as the _to_ marks the infinitive verb phrase. The _to_ is required, but  the _for_ is optional, unless it comes at the beginning of a sentence. So, they're both correct and mean the same thing. Speaker's choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather tricky question. Although **prefer** can certainly be used transitively with a to-infinitival following the object, the inclusion of 'for' before the direct object is not ungrammatical per se. There may be limitations on its use, and it may subtly alter the meaning. This usage of for + DO + to-infinitive is more general than this particular example, and is analysed by Jackie Nordstrom in [Modality and Subordinators](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=86v3bjkjYskC&pg=PA261&lpg=PA261&dq=%22prefer-for%22+Pesetsky&source=bl&ots=kiN3SMQF2R&sig=GJh4mlYsqh0ffKXW6unEmIVDu3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBWoVChMIu9HMlcvCyAIVxtoaCh2Mlg10#v=onepage&q=%22prefer-for%22%20Pesetsky&f=false) (slightly tweaked / reformatted):

> [It] will be demonstrated that *for* in the *for-to* construction must
>   be considered a preposition, like its homonym from which it derives.
>
> Interestingly, the *for-to* construction can be associated with
>   modality. Pesetsky and Torrego (2004) have observed that the *for-to*
>   construction occurs in *irrealis* (non-actualized) contexts, or generic
>   contexts:
>
> (a) I would prefer/like for Sue to buy the book [non-actualized]
>
> (b) I always prefer for my students to buy this book. [generic]
>
> According to Palmer (2001) the habitual can also be categorized as
>   irrealis, since it refers to tendencies rather than actual events.
>   Following Palmer's wide definition of 'irrealis', *for* may therefore be
>   considered an irrealis complementizer ...
>
> More precisely, the *for-to* construction can be connected with event
>   modality. The matrix predicate can have volative, obligative, or
>   abilitative meanings:
>
> (c) We want/prefer/desire for you to partake.
>
> (d) It is necessary/mandatory/obligatory for you to partake.
>
> (e) It is possible/doable/feasible for you to partake.
>
> Furthermore, the for-to construction can be connected with the future,
>   another non-actualized category, in the sense that it often has (i)
>   future reference (specific or generic).
>
> After certain adjectival predicates, on the other hand, the
>   construction simply has (ii) generic reference:
>
> (i) We have arranged for the meeting to be held on Tuesday. [future]
>
> (ii) It is rare for the bus to be late. [no future reference; generic]

In the actual example, the unrealised / future nature certainly licenses the '... prefer for me to ...' version. And I'd say that the for-less version is more of an 'A or B?' sort of question, whereas the version with 'for' is more suggestive of 'A/B, or not?' question. Though one couldn't guarantee that this was intended.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prefer) of “prefer”, it is a transitive verb, therefore it needs no prepositions.

Thus your first sentence is wrong in this case and should not include the preposition “for”. I assume you mean your sentence as a reply to someone inviting you to their place, e.g. "Sure you can come and get it!" "Would you prefer me to come in today or tomorrow?"

In the [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/prefer) you can see all the different constructions of “prefer”, in you example the correct one is

> **prefer someone to do something:** I’d prefer you to drive, if you don’t mind.

[Other examples](http://absolutewrite.com/forums/showthread.php?291151-Is-there-a-certain-time-you-would-prefer-I-call-you)

> “Is there a certain time you would prefer I call you?”
>
> “Do you prefer I call you at a certain time?”

Answer (score 0):

I think the best construction would be: "Would you [prefer that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22887/i-would-prefer-it-if-the-meeting-would-be-was-postponed) I come in today or tomorrow?"